# How to generate an OAuth nonce in android?

Tags: android, oauth, nonce

To generate a OAuth nonce in android I tried -

```
                byte[] nonce = new byte[16];

                try {
                    rand = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
                } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                String oauth_nonce = rand.toString();

                Log.d("nonce value", oauth_nonce);
```

It gives something like - `java.security.SecureRandom@58957gy8`

Is this the correct way to generate a nonce ? If no, can you suggest a correct way ?

Comment: how did you solve this problem @ronn? Did you use the method below?

Answer (score 5):

You can try with this

```
import java.util.UUID;


String nonce = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```